# Pass variable value from aspx link button to code behind in ASP. NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Inside a for loop, how to pass the variable to the code-behind from an asp tag and access the variable value

`CommandArgument` works but shows `<# gigs[x].Id%>` - not the value.

**Aspx**

```
<%for (int x = 0; x < gigs.Count; x++){%>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="btn btn-danger mt-3" runat="server" 
     UseSubmitBehavior="false" CommandArgument="<# gigs[x].Id%>" 
     OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Hide Gig <i class="fa fa-eye-slash ml-1"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
    String Value1 = lnk.CommandArgument;
    Response.Write(Value1);
}
```

**Result**

```
<# gigs[x].Id%>
```

**Expected Result**

1

Answer (score 1):

Try using `<%# gigs[x].Id %>` instead and call `Page.DataBind()` on the `Page_Load` event.

<%= %> is a shortened response.Write() and is never valid as an attribute, for any server tag.

<%# %> can be used, only if the container is databound (the page in your case).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the knowledge you shared. Still, I'm getting the result as <# gigs[x].Id%>

Comment: Missed the % symbol after opening tag <

`CommandArgument="<%# gigs[x].Id %>" `

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

You're much better off using a Strongly Typed Repeater. You can set the `ItemType` as your class `gigs` and have full access to all it's properties. Then you can easily use them in the LinkButton.

```
Repeater1.DataSource = gigs;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And then in the aspx

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ItemType="MyNameSpace.MyClass.Gig">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CommandArgument='<%# Item.Id %>' OnClick="LinkButton2_Click" runat="server">Hide Gig</asp:LinkButton>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```